Unable to connect using IgniteThinDriver
I am using Ignite 2.16.0 and have my server running configured to be a read-through and write-through cache. The client cache works fine when using the key-value look from the cache.
I want to connect using the JDBC Driver and query the data from the cache but I always get an error table name not found when I query using the cache name.
Can someone help me with this issue?
tried various approaches

Please share how you created the table.
